# Knapsack: how to add item type to existing solution

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I've been working with this variation of dynamic programming to solve a knapsack problem:

```
KnapsackItem = Struct.new(:name, :cost, :value)
KnapsackProblem = Struct.new(:items, :max_cost)


def dynamic_programming_knapsack(problem)
  num_items = problem.items.size
  items = problem.items
  max_cost = problem.max_cost

  cost_matrix = zeros(num_items, max_cost+1)

  num_items.times do |i|
    (max_cost + 1).times do |j|
      if(items[i].cost > j)
        cost_matrix[i][j] = cost_matrix[i-1][j]
      else
        cost_matrix[i][j] = [cost_matrix[i-1][j], items[i].value + cost_matrix[i-1][j-items[i].cost]].max
      end
    end
  end

  cost_matrix
end

def get_used_items(problem, cost_matrix)
  i = cost_matrix.size - 1
  currentCost = cost_matrix[0].size - 1
  marked = Array.new(cost_matrix.size, 0) 

  while(i >= 0 && currentCost >= 0)
    if(i == 0 && cost_matrix[i][currentCost] > 0 ) || (cost_matrix[i][currentCost] != cost_matrix[i-1][currentCost])
      marked[i] = 1
      currentCost -= problem.items[i].cost
    end
    i -= 1
  end
  marked
end
```

This has worked great for the structure above where you simply provide a name, cost and value. Items can be created like the following:

```
 items = [
      KnapsackItem.new('david lee', 8000, 30) , 
      KnapsackItem.new('kevin love', 12000, 50), 
      KnapsackItem.new('kemba walker', 7300, 10),
      KnapsackItem.new('jrue holiday', 12300, 30),
      KnapsackItem.new('stephen curry', 10300, 80),
      KnapsackItem.new('lebron james', 5300, 90),
      KnapsackItem.new('kevin durant', 2300, 30),
      KnapsackItem.new('russell westbrook', 9300, 30),
      KnapsackItem.new('kevin martin', 8300, 15),
      KnapsackItem.new('steve nash', 4300, 15),
      KnapsackItem.new('kyle lowry', 6300, 20),
      KnapsackItem.new('monta ellis', 8300, 30),
      KnapsackItem.new('dirk nowitzki', 7300, 25),
      KnapsackItem.new('david lee', 9500, 35),
      KnapsackItem.new('klay thompson', 6800, 28)
    ]

  problem = KnapsackProblem.new(items, 65000)
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that I need to add a position for each of these players and I have to let the knapsack algorithm know that it still needs to maximize value across all players, except there is a new restriction and that restriction is each player has a position and each position can only be selected a certain amount of times. Some positions can be selected twice, others once. Items would ideally become this:

```
KnapsackItem = Struct.new(:name, :cost, :position, :value)
```

Positions would have a restriction such as the following:

```
PositionLimits = Struct.new(:position, :max)
```

Limits would be instantiated perhaps like the following:

```
limits = [Struct.new('PG', 2), Struct.new('C', 1), Struct.new('SF', 2), Struct.new('PF', 2), Struct.new('Util', 2)]
```

What makes this a little more tricky is every player can be in the Util position. If we want to disable the Util position, we will just set the 2 to 0.

Our original items array would look something like the following:

```
items = [
          KnapsackItem.new('david lee', 'PF', 8000, 30) , 
          KnapsackItem.new('kevin love', 'C', 12000, 50), 
          KnapsackItem.new('kemba walker', 'PG', 7300, 10),
          ... etc ...
        ]
```

How can position restrictions be added to the knapsack algorithm in order to still retain max value for the provided player pool provided?

Comment: If you are not too much specific on ruby implementation, then it will be simpler to understand if you describe your problem in simple non-code language.

Comment: I could use some help with getting this implemented in Ruby, so I did add a bounty to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to incorporate this additional constraint, you may have to either go through a bit of brute-force or Integer Linear Programming solving. Are you open for these or you specifically want a dynamic programming solution?

Comment: I'm open to anything really -- the amount of items that need to be ran through knapsack really won't ever be > 50-60, so not terribly worried about computation time as long as end result is accurate.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with my solution. I have given you a recurrence equation that can be solved using DP as before. Have i miss understood the question?

Answer (score 4):

There are some efficient libraries available in ruby which could suit your task , Its clear that you are looking for some [constrain based optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) , there are some libraries in ruby which are a opensource so, free to use , Just include them in you project. All you need to do is generate [Linear programming](http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/lp-format.htm) model objective function out of your constrains and library's optimizer would generate Solution which satisfy all your constrains , or says no solution exists if nothing can be concluded out of the given constrains .

Some such libraries available in ruby are

- [RGLPK](http://rubygems.org/gems/rglpk)
- [OPL](http://rubygems.org/gems/opl)
- [LP Solve](https://rubygems.org/gems/lpsolve)

OPL follows the LP syntax similar to IBM CPLEX , which is widely used Optimization software, So you could get good references on how to model the LP using this , Moreover this is build on top of the RGLPK.

Comment: Any chance you can share how I would plugin my variables into any of these gems? Not entirely sure where I would have to start.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the additional constraint that you are specifying is as following:

> There shall be a set of elements, out which only at most k (k = 1 or
>   2) elements can be selected in the solution. There shall be multiple
>   such sets.

There are two approaches that come to my mind, neither of which are efficient enough.

Approach 1:

1. Divide the elements into groups of positions. So if there are 5 positions, then each element shall be assigned to one of 5 groups.
2. Iterate (or recur) through all the combinations by selecting 1 (or 2) element from each group and checking the total value and cost. There are ways in which you can fathom some combinations. For example, in a group if there are two elements in which one gives more value at lesser cost, then the other can be rejected from all solutions.

Approach 2:

```
Mixed Integer Linear Programming Approach.
```

Formulate the problem as follows:

```
Maximize summation (ViXi) {i = 1 to N} 
where Vi is value and 
Xi is a 1/0 variable denoting presence/absence of an element from the solution.

Subject to constraints:
summation (ciXi) <= C_MAX {total cost}
And for each group:
summation (Xj) <= 1 (or 2 depending on position)
All Xi = 0 or 1.
```

And then you will have to find a solver to solve the above MILP.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to a constraint vehicle routing problem. You can try a heuristic like the saving algorithm from Clarke&Wright. You can also try a brute-force algorithm with less players.

Answer (score 0):

Considering players have Five positions your knapsack problem would be:-

```
   Knpsk(W,N,PG,C,SF,PF,Util) = max(Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,...)+Value[N],Knpsk(W,N-1,PG,C,SF,PF,Util),Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,PG,C,SF,PF,Util-1)+Value[N])

    if(Pos[N]=="PG") then Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,....) = Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,PG-1,....)

    if(Pos[N]=="C") then Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,....) = Knpsk(W-Cost[N],N-1,PG,C-1....)

    so on...

  PG,C,SF,PF,Util are current position capacities 
  W is current knapsack capacity
  N number of items available
```

Dynamic Programming can be used as before using 7-D table and as in your case the values of positions are small it will slow down algorithm by factor of 16 which is great for n-p complete problem

Following is dynamic programming solution in JAVA:

```
public class KnapsackSolver {

    HashMap CostMatrix;
    // Maximum capacities for positions
    int posCapacity[] = {2,1,2,2,2};
    // Total positions 
    String[] positions = {"PG","C","SF","PF","util"}; 
    ArrayList playerSet = new ArrayList<player>();  
    public ArrayList solutionSet;
    public int bestCost;


    class player {

        int value;
        int cost;
        int pos;
        String name;

        public player(int value,int cost,int pos,String name) {
            this.value = value;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.pos = pos;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return("'"+name+"'"+", "+value+", "+cost+", "+positions[pos]);
        }

    }

    // Used to add player to list of available players
    void  additem(String name,int cost,int value,String pos) {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<positions.length;i++) {
            if(pos.equals(positions[i]))
                break;
        }
        playerSet.add(new player(value,cost,i,name));
    }

    // Converts subproblem data to string for hashing
    public String encode(int Capacity,int Totalitems,int[] positions) {
        String Data = Capacity+","+Totalitems;
        for(int i=0;i<positions.length;i++) {
            Data = Data + "," + positions[i];
        }
        return(Data);
    }

    // Check if subproblem is in hash tables
    int isDone(int capacity,int players,int[] positions) {

        String k = encode(capacity,players,positions);

        if(CostMatrix.containsKey(k)) {
            //System.out.println("Key found: "+k+" "+(Integer)CostMatrix.get(k));
            return((Integer)CostMatrix.get(k));
        }

        return(-1);
    }

    // Adds subproblem added hash table
    void addEncode(int capacity,int players,int[] positions,int value) {

        String k = encode(capacity,players,positions);
        CostMatrix.put(k, value);
    }

    boolean checkvalid(int capacity,int players) {

        return(!(capacity<1||players<0));
    }

    // Solve the Knapsack recursively with Hash look up
    int solve(int capacity,int players,int[] posCapacity) {

        // Check if sub problem is valid

        if(checkvalid(capacity,players)) {

            //System.out.println("Processing: "+encode(capacity,players,posCapacity));

            player current = (player)playerSet.get(players);

            int sum1 = 0,sum2 = 0,sum3 = 0;

            int temp = isDone(capacity,players-1,posCapacity);

            // Donot add player

            if(temp>-1) {

                sum1 = temp;
            }
            else sum1 = solve(capacity,players-1,posCapacity);

            //check if current player can be added to knapsack

            if(capacity>=current.cost) {

                posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]--;

                temp = isDone(capacity-current.cost,players-1,posCapacity);

                posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]++;

                // Add player to util

                if(posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]>0) {

                    if(temp>-1) {

                        sum2 = temp+current.value;
                    }
                    else {

                        posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]--;
                        sum2 = solve(capacity-current.cost,players-1,posCapacity)+current.value;
                        posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]++;

                    }

                }

                // Add player at its position

                int i = current.pos;

                    if(posCapacity[i]>0) {

                        posCapacity[i]--;
                        temp  = isDone(capacity-current.cost,players-1,posCapacity);
                        posCapacity[i]++;
                        if(temp>-1) {

                            sum3 = temp+current.value;
                        }
                        else {

                            posCapacity[i]--;
                            sum3 = solve(capacity-current.cost,players-1,posCapacity)+current.value;
                            posCapacity[i]++;

                        }
                    }
                }   

            //System.out.println(sum1+ " "+ sum2+ " " + sum3 );


            // Evaluate the maximum of all subproblem   
            int res = Math.max(Math.max(sum1,sum2), sum3);

            //add current solution to Hash table
            addEncode(capacity, players, posCapacity,res);
            //System.out.println("Encoding: "+encode(capacity,players,posCapacity)+" Cost: "+res);

            return(res);


        }
        return(0);
    }

    void getSolution(int capacity,int players,int[] posCapacity) {


        if(players>=0) {
           player curr = (player)playerSet.get(players);
           int bestcost = isDone(capacity,players,posCapacity);
           int sum1 = 0,sum2 = 0,sum3 = 0;
           //System.out.println(encode(capacity,players-1,posCapacity)+" "+bestcost);
           sum1 = isDone(capacity,players-1,posCapacity);
           posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]--;
           sum2 = isDone(capacity-curr.cost,players-1,posCapacity) + curr.value;
           posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]++;
           posCapacity[curr.pos]--;        
           sum3 = isDone(capacity-curr.cost,players-1,posCapacity) + curr.value;
           posCapacity[curr.pos]++;

           if(bestcost==0)
               return;

           // Check if player is not added
           if(sum1==bestcost) {
               getSolution(capacity,players-1,posCapacity);
           }
           // Check if player is added to util
           else if(sum2==bestcost) {
               solutionSet.add(curr);
               //System.out.println(positions[posCapacity.length-1]+" added");
               posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]--;
               getSolution(capacity-curr.cost,players-1,posCapacity);
               posCapacity[posCapacity.length-1]++;

           }
           else {
               solutionSet.add(curr);
               //System.out.println(positions[curr.pos]+" added");
               posCapacity[curr.pos]--;
               getSolution(capacity-curr.cost,players-1,posCapacity);
               posCapacity[curr.pos]++;     


           }   
        }


   }



    void getOptSet(int capacity) {

        CostMatrix = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        bestCost = solve(capacity,playerSet.size()-1,posCapacity);
        solutionSet = new ArrayList<player>();
        getSolution(capacity, playerSet.size()-1, posCapacity);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KnapsackSolver ks = new KnapsackSolver();
        ks.additem("david lee", 8000, 30, "PG"); 
        ks.additem("kevin love", 12000, 50, "C"); 
        ks.additem("kemba walker", 7300, 10, "SF");
        ks.additem("jrue holiday", 12300, 30, "PF");
        ks.additem("stephen curry", 10300, 80, "PG");
        ks.additem("lebron james", 5300, 90, "PG");
        ks.additem("kevin durant", 2300, 30, "C");
        ks.additem("russell westbrook", 9300, 30, "SF");
        ks.additem("kevin martin", 8300, 15, "PF");
        ks.additem("steve nash", 4300, 15, "C");
        ks.additem("kyle lowry", 6300, 20, "PG");
        ks.additem("monta ellis", 8300, 30, "C");
        ks.additem("dirk nowitzki", 7300, 25, "SF");
        ks.additem("david lee", 9500, 35, "PF");
        ks.additem("klay thompson", 6800, 28,"PG");
        //System.out.println("Items added...");
       // System.out.println(ks.playerSet);
        int maxCost = 30000;
        ks.getOptSet(maxCost);
        System.out.println("Best Value: "+ks.bestCost);
        System.out.println("Solution Set: "+ks.solutionSet);
    }




}
```

**Note:** If players with certain positions are added more than its capacity then those added as util because players from any position can be added to util.

Comment: Just to clarify before I try to break down your solution and figure out how to bake it into my code above, is W and N additional positions you made up for the purpose of this example?

Comment: W is knapsack capacity in your case max_cost & N is the number of players in your case.

Comment: Vikram - I ran your code and I have 2 comments. 1) In getSolution you assign to sum3, but never use its value.  Was that intentional 2) I don't believe your results are what he OP was looking for.  Lets assume that you have positions C, G, F and U (which is a wildcard of C G and F).  Assume you need 1C, 2G, 2F, and 1U.  Your solution appears to solve for a max of each position, when I'm guessing the OP (and myself) would like to have a solution that has EXACTLY that number from each position. Essentially you want to put together the best (weight) team that fits under the maxCost.

Comment: @user1146334 yes we donot need sum3 because it is obvious that if player is not added to util then it is added at its position(forgot to remove it).

Comment: @user1146334 I had the same doubts as you after i posted this answer so asked OP about it but he didnt reply. (check my comments above). If that the case then its not a knapsack problem at all but good solutions can be found by rather easy implementation of genetic algorithm. I think the problem becomes harder with those constraints